# Cannot execute binary file error

Tags: linux

I just a ran simple hello world program in my linux it worked perfectly.when i supposed to ran same file in the hand held device (running on the linux os)i got the error like Cannot execute binary file error.i am completely new to linux.

can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you re-compile for the hand held device, or did you just try to run the same executable ? What is the architecture of each platform ?

Comment: Binary executables are platform-dependant. You need to compile for the target architecture if it differs.

Comment: the device running on linux kernal GNU/2.6.26....

Comment: The kernel version matters less than the CPU of the device.  If you've compiled your binary for an Intel PC on your desk, that binary won't run on your handheld if your device is ARM based.

Comment: Does 'noexec' set on the mounted partition,where you ran the executable file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run binary file in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477157/how-to-run-binary-file-in-linux)

Answer (score 3):

Just because the OS is the same does not mean an executable will run. The binary file is composed of machine instructions the processor can understand. Moving back and forth between processors with the compatible instruction sets will normally work fine, but if they are not compatible the CPU will not be able to understand the instructions.

Most Intel processors use a x86 ISA (instruction set architecture), that your mobile processor is likely not compatible with.

Comment: To be more specific, the mobile processor is probably [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture)-based.

Answer (score 1):

Just a heads up because I had this problem but the b4-bit application for 32-bit OS didnt work for me.  If your in linux you probably need a gcc compiler on the backend of terminal that might not be installed.  If you dont have this Linux doesnt seem to know how to read the file.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
su <user-name>
```

Then command/file should be executed.